# Auto completion search with Solr using NGrams

Tags: autocomplete, solr, n-gram

I'm working on auto completion search with [Solr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Solr) using EdgeNGrams. If the user is searching for names of employees, then auto completion should be applied. That is, I want the results to be like a Google search. It's working fine for some searches.

File `schema.xml`:

```xml
<fieldType name="edgytext" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" side="front" />
    </analyzer>
```

```xml
<field name="title" type="edgytext" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true"/>
<field name="empname" type="edgytext" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" />

<field name="autocomplete_text" type="edgytext" indexed="true" stored="false"  multiValued="true" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="false" />
<copyField source="empname" dest="autocomplete_text"/>

<copyField source="title" dest="autocomplete_text"/>
```

---

```
 http://local:8080/test/suggest/?q=michael
```

Result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">1</int>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0" />
    <lst name="spellcheck">
        <lst name="suggestions">
            <lst name="michael">
                <int name="numFound">9</int>
                <int name="startOffset">0</int>
                <int name="endOffset">7</int>
                <arr name="suggestion">
                    <str>michael bolton</str>
                    <str>michael foret</str>
                    <str>michael houser</str>
                    <str>michael o'brien</str>
                    <str>michael penn</str>
                    <str>michael row your boat ashore</str>
                    <str>michael tilson thomas</str>
                    <str>michael w. smith</str>
                    <str>michael w. smith featuring andrae crouch</str>
                </arr>
            </lst>
            <str name="collation">michael bolton</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
</response>
```

It's working fine for me. When I search with `michael f`

```
http:// local:8080/test/suggest/?q=michael f
```

I get a response like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">1</int>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0" />
    <lst name="spellcheck">
        <lst name="suggestions">
            <lst name="michael">
                <int name="numFound">9</int>
                <int name="startOffset">0</int>
                <int name="endOffset">7</int>
                <arr name="suggestion">
                    <str>michael bolton</str>
                    <str>michael foret</str>
                    <str>michael houser</str>
                    <str>michael o'brien</str>
                    <str>michael penn</str>
                    <str>michael row your boat ashore</str>
                    <str>michael tilson thomas</str>
                    <str>michael w. smith</str>
                    <str>michael w. smith featuring andrae crouch</str>
                </arr>
            </lst>
            <lst name="f">
                <int name="numFound">10</int>
                <int name="startOffset">8</int>
                <int name="endOffset">9</int>
                <arr name="suggestion">
                    <str>f**k the facts</str>
                    <str>fairest lord jesus</str>
                    <str>fatboy slim</str>
                    <str>ffh</str>
                    <str>fiona apple</str>
                    <str>foo fighters</str>
                    <str>frank sinatra</str>
                    <str>frans bauer</str>
                    <str>franz ferdinand</str>
                    <str>françois rauber</str>
                </arr>
            </lst>
            <str name="collation">michael bolton f**k the facts</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
</response>.
```

When I search with `michael f` then, I should get `michael foret` only. Data coming starts with `f`. Is there anything wrong in my configuration settings in Solr?

Comment: Here's one example implementation - [Solr Powered ISFDB – Part #9: Autocomplete](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2011/04/08/solr-powered-isfdb-part-9/).
You do need to read the whole series, but it is a great introduction to Solr.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Your schema looks good at first glance, did you reindex your data after applying changes? On which field are you searching? You can also have a look at the Solr analysis page to see how the query is parsed and how your data are indexed.

Comment: Could you please accept one of the answers that you got if they were useful?

Comment: Thanks, still my problem was not solved... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174672/suggesterauto-completion-search-in-solr-using-ngrams-one-collation-for-sugges

Comment: Got solved. below link is post. http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/auto-completion-search-with-solr-using-NGrams-in-SOLR-td3998559.html

Answer (score 7):

I wrote [old link] about different ways to make auto-suggestions with Solr and some questions you should ask yourself in order to make the right choice. Briefly, the out-of-the-box ways are:

- Facet prefix
- NGrams
- TermsComponent
- Suggester

They all have advantages and limitations at the same time, I'd suggest you to read the article.

If you are looking for a complete and flexible solution, which requires some more work, you can have a look at [this article](http://www.cominvent.com/2012/01/25/super-flexible-autocomplete-with-solr/) as well.

If you already decided to use NGrams, given your examples you can index your employees using [EdgeNGramFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters/#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory) with minGramSize 1, then search on that field to make auto-suggestions. For the client part you need to use some javascript.

Comment: thanks for reply

below is my code in schema.xml

<fieldType name='edgytext' class='solr.TextField' positionIncrementGap='100'>
 <analyzer type='index'>
  <tokenizer class='solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory' /> 
  <filter class='solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory' /> 
  <filter class='solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory' minGramSize='1' maxGramSize='15' /> 
  </analyzer>
 <analyzer type='query'>
  <tokenizer class='solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory' /> 
  <filter class='solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory' /> 
  </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
<field name='empname' type='edgytext' indexed='true' stored='true' />

Comment: <field name='autocomplete_text' type='edgytext' indexed='true' stored='true' omitNorms='true' omitTermFreqAndPositions='true' /> 
<copyField source='empname' dest='text' /> 

when im searching with name 'mado' or 'madonna' getting employees names.But when searching with 'madon' not getting any data.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add these details please? Your schema looks good at first glance, did you reindex your data after applying changes? On which field are you searching? You can also have a look at the Solr analysis page to see how the query is parsed and how your data are indexed.

Comment: im searching on both title and empname fields.

Comment: Got solved. below link is my post.                  http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/auto-completion-search-with-solr-using-NGrams-in-SOLR-td3998559.html