# Suggester(Auto completion) search in solr using NGrams (one collation for Suggester Component)

Tags: autocomplete, solr, collation, autosuggest

Im working on auto completion search with solr using EdgeNGrams.I use solr 3.3 and I would like to use collations from suggester as a autocomplete solution for multi term searches. Unfortunately the Suggester returns only one collation for a multi term search

If the user is searching for names of employees, then auto completion should be applied. ie., want results like google search.  It's working fine for me below configurations.

### schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="edgytext" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" /> 
  <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
 <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" /> 
 <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
 <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" side="front" />    
</analyzer>
```

```
<field name="title" type="edgytext" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true"/>
<field name="empname" type="edgytext" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" />

<field name="autocomplete_text" type="edgytext" indexed="true" stored="false"  multiValued="true" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="false" />
<copyField source="empname" dest="autocomplete_text"/>

<copyField source="title" dest="autocomplete_text"/>
```

---

URL : $http://local:8080/test/suggest/?q=michael

```
   Result :
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int> 
<int name="QTime">1</int> 
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0" /> 
<lst name="spellcheck">
<lst name="suggestions">
<lst name="michael">
<int name="numFound">9</int> 
<int name="startOffset">0</int> 
<int name="endOffset">7</int> 
<arr name="suggestion">
  <str>michael bolton</str> 
  <str>michael foret</str> 
  <str>michael force</str>
  <str>michael w. smith featuring andrae crouch</str> 
</arr>
</lst>
<str name="collation">michael bolton</str> 
</lst>
</lst>
</response>
```

It's working fine for me. When im searching with "michael f", getting response like below. (http://local:8080/test/suggest/?q=michael f)

Response :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 <response>
 <lst name="responseHeader">
 <int name="status">0</int> 
 <int name="QTime">1</int> 
 </lst>
 <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0" /> 
<lst name="spellcheck">
<lst name="suggestions">
<lst name="michael">
<int name="numFound">9</int> 
<int name="startOffset">0</int> 
<int name="endOffset">7</int> 
<arr name="suggestion">
  <str>michael bolton</str> 
  <str>michael foret</str> 
  <str>michael force</str> 
  <str>michael w. smith featuring andrae crouch</str> 
   .....
</arr>
</lst>
<lst name="f">
<int name="numFound">10</int> 
<int name="startOffset">8</int> 
<int name="endOffset">9</int> 
<arr name="suggestion">
  <str>f**k the facts</str> 
  <str>fairest lord jesus</str> 
  <str>franz ferdinand</str> 
  <str>françois rauber</str> 
  .........
</arr>
</lst>
<str name="collation">michael bolton f**k the facts</str> 
</lst>
</lst>
</response>.
```

So when i search with "michael f" then, i should get "michael foret" and "michael force" only. Data coming starts with "f". Please suggest me if there's anything wrong in my configuration settings in solr.

Thanks in Advance,

Anil.

Comment: Could you post the configuration of the Suggester component in your `solrconfig.xml`. Usually one chooses between the Suggester and making NGrams. What fieldType have you configured for the Suggester?

Comment: <searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
 <lst name="spellchecker">
   <str name="name">suggest</str> 
   <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str> 
   <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.FSTLookup</str>
   <str name="storeDir">suggest</str> 
   <str name="field">autocomplete_text</str> 
   <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str> 
   <int name="weightBuckets">100</int>
 </lst>
</searchComponent>

Comment: <requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest" startup="lazy">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="spellcheck">true</str> 
    <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str> 
    <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str> 
    <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str> 
    <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str> 
   </lst>
  <arr name="last-components">
  <str>suggest</str> 
   </arr>
  </requestHandler>

Comment: still not solved my problem...

Comment: Finall got solved Autocomplete functionality using TermsComponent. check this link.                                   http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/auto-completion-search-with-solr-using-NGrams-in-SOLR-td3998559.html